# Как в Sublime Text в плагине Terminal использовать другую консоль (другой shell)?

Tags: bash, консоль, sublime-text, sublime-text-3, putty

Я пытаюсь запустить консоль Putty в Sublime Text через плагин Terminal. 
Консоль открыватся, но не может запустить gulp.
Если консоль открыть напрямую - gulp запускается корректно.

Сообщения в консоли при ошибках

```
bash: cut: command not found

user@LenovoG510  ~/Desktop/Проекты учебные/Gulp/test_gulp/gulp and workflow (master)
$ gulp
/c/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/npm/gulp: line 2: sed: command not found
/c/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/npm/gulp: line 2: dirname: command not found
/c/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/npm/gulp: line 4: uname: command not found
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\Git\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:425:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:146:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:540:3
```

Конфиг плагина Terminal

```
{
    // The command to execute for the terminal, leave blank for the OS default
    // See https://github.com/wbond/sublime_terminal#examples for examples
    "terminal": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\mintty.exe",
    "parameters": []
}
```

Comment: Для начала - я бы грохнул все папки с кириллицей и пробелами.

Comment: Это очевидно. Но это не решает проблему.

Comment: Ещё вопрос. Зачем putty, если есть нативный ssh? Или ты из винды хочешь дёргать по ссх баш ни линуксе?

Answer (score 0):

Введите в терминал это npm root или npm root -g это, что бы проверить как именно установлен gulp (/Users/USERNAME/GulpPack/node_modules, если так, то он у вас локально, нужно, что бы было глобально)
введите в консоль config set prefix /usr/local и затем еще раз проверьте gulp через команду npm root -g
В консоли должно быть выведено такое сообщение /usr/local/lib/node_modules